# Takes long to turn on with memory card but not without it

Tags: dslr, memory-card, sdcard

My camera used to turn on regularly and begin functions normally and I'm not sure how long ago it was but after not using my camera for a while I turned it on and the image would load and you can see throught the camera perfectly but there are no functions on the screen and no buttons will work for about a minute then it all works perfectly. I took out the memory card and turned on my camera and it turned on normally like it used to with all the functions and buttons working but if the memory card is in it takes a minute or two to work.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this or at least what is wrong?

Comment: does this happen with EVERY memory card, or just one?

Comment: Have you tried doing a full reformat of the memory card? It sounds like it may be taking your camera that long to read files or a file directory that are on the card.

Comment: Thank you both for the help and I guess i could have tried it earlier but it was just that memory card I tried another and the camera worked fine. I guess the memory card was just done, so thank you drinxy and michael (:

Comment: sounds like the memory card was corrupt. Formatting it may help as Michael suggested, but if it gives you any more problems get rid of it. You don't want it to die with important data on it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing a full reformat of the memory card? It sounds like it may be taking your camera that long to read files or a file directory that are on the card.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check contacts on the card and clean them if needed
2. Try reformatting the card using [sdformatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/), which makes proper and more thorough format than the camera and often helps with similar issues

Answer (score 1):

Doing a full format will do the trick. Go to disk management on your system and right click on it as well as choose to format. That's the best way to ensure that everything is erased on the card and you may start storing photos from scratch.

Good luck!!